# object.Storage.js - creates a namespace for Storage

Tags: javascript

This basically creates a namespace for Storage among other things.  I'm looking for feedback on the structure of the code.

```
/******************************************************************************************************************(120)
** Storage
** - Dependencies - None
** - Basically creates a namespace for Storage facilities
** - Used to manage local and session storage for login purposes
** - Note - underscore each() will error on web storage because of the length property
*/

    var Storage = $A.Obj.create('public', {
        Name: 'Storage',
        S: {

            // will point to localStorage or sessionStorage
            storage:     null,

            // namespace for this class - note all librarys use the same web storage
            ns:          'arc_',

            // check this identifier in local storage to see if a user is logged in
            identifier:  'arc_h_token'
        },
        init: function () {

            // always use localStorage for now - removed checkbox
            this.S.storage = localStorage;

            // if the token is in localStorage a user is already logged in permanently
            // this.S.storage = localStorage[this.S.identifier] ? localStorage : sessionStorage;
        },
        setToken: function (value) {
            localStorage[this.S.identifier] = value;
        },

        // Utility Fucntions below
        // clear all namespace properties
        clear: function () {
            $A.someKey(this.S.storage, function (val, key) {
                if (key.slice(0, this.S.ns.length) === this.S.ns) {
                    this.S.storage.removeItem(key);
                }
            }, this);
        },
        set: function (key, value) {
            this.S.storage[this.S.ns + key] = value;
        },
        get: function (key) {
            return this.S.storage[this.S.ns + key];
        },
        setObj: function (o) {
            $A.someKey(o, function (val, key) {
                this.S.storage[this.S.ns + key] = val;
            }, this);
        },
        getObj: function () {
            var o = {};
            $A.someKey(this.S.storage, function (val, key) {
                if (key.slice(0, this.S.ns.length) === this.S.ns) {
                    o[key.slice(this.S.ns.length)] = val;
                }
            }, this);
            return o;
        }
    });
```

Comment: This question has been [mentioned on Meta](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/6778/9357).

Comment: What is `$A`? Some speculated it was [`$A` from PrototypeJS](http://api.prototypejs.org/language/dollar-A/) but that doesn't appear to have an `Obj` property...

Answer (score 1):

`S`, `ns` and `identifier` could be a bit more descriptive (although `S` also seems to add no value anyway and its properties could easily be moved to the main object).

`storage` doesn't seem to serve a real purpose.